# Помогите реализовать крестик, который задвигает меню обратно за экран

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

При помощи input я выдвигаю панель, но програмируя так же и крестик () задвинуть обратно не получается, как по другому можно реализовывать данные меню

```css
.top-panel {
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(200%);
}
/* Блок сообщения */
.message {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    padding: 3em 2em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 980px
}

/* Переключатель панели */
label.btn {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.17,0.04,0.03,0.94);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
    z-index: 2
}

.open:checked ~ .top-panel  {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s
}
.open:checked ~ label.btn{
 display: none;
}
.open:checked ~ .soc {
 display: none;
}
.open:checked ~ .soc_text {
 display: none;
}
 
.open:not(:checked) ~ .top-panel {
    -webkit-transition: 0.35s;
    -moz-transition: 0.35s;
    transition: 0.35s
}
 
.open:checked ~ .top-panel > label.btn {
    background: #dd6149
}

#navigation{
 font-size: 15px;
 color:#38AE48;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.2em;
 padding-bottom: 50px
}
.fa-times{
 position: absolute;
 right: 20px;
 top:50px; 
 color:#FFF;
}
.message a{
 display: block;
 font-size:20px;
 color:#FFF;
 letter-spacing: 0.05em;
 font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
 padding-top:20px;
}

#menu_descr{
 font-size: 15px;
 color:#414141;
 margin-top:50px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.soc_net i{
 color:#414141;
 margin-right:  20px;
 margin-left:3px;
}
```

```html
<input class="open" id="top-box" type="checkbox" hidden>
       <label class="btn fas fa-bars fa-2x" for="top-box"></label>
           <div class="top-panel">
               <div class="message wow fadeInLeft">
                      <p id="navigation">navigation<i class="fas fa-times "></i></p>
                      <a href="#">Home</a>
                      <a href="#">About</a>
                      <a href="#">Services</a>
                      <a href="#">Works</a>
                      <a href="#">Cliens</a>
                      <a href="#">Contacts</a>
                      <p id="menu_descr">Perspiciatis hic praesentium nesciunt. Et neque a dolorum voluptatem porro iusto sequi veritatis libero enim. Iusto id suscipit veritatis neque reprehenderit.</p>
                      <div class="soc_net">
                       <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
                       <i class="fab fa-instagram  fa-2x"></i>
                       <i class="fab fa-facebook  fa-2x"></i>
                       <i class="fab fa-vk  fa-2x"></i>
                      </div>
               </div>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто не надо скрывать label, а с помощью псевдоэлементов этого лейбла (before и after) можно нарисовать крестик:

```css
.top-panel {
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateX(200%);
}
/* Блок сообщения */
.message {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    padding: 3em 2em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 980px
}

/* Переключатель панели */
label.btn {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.17,0.04,0.03,0.94);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
    z-index: 2;
}

.open:checked ~ .top-panel  {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s
}
.open:checked ~ label.btn:before,
.open:checked ~ label.btn:after{
 content: '';
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
    transition: 0.5s
}
.open:checked ~ label.btn:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.open:checked ~ label.btn:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.open:checked ~ .soc {
 display: none;
}
.open:checked ~ .soc_text {
 display: none;
}
 
.open:not(:checked) ~ .top-panel {
    -webkit-transition: 0.35s;
    -moz-transition: 0.35s;
    transition: 0.35s
}
 
.open:checked ~ .top-panel > label.btn {
    background: #dd6149;
}

#navigation{
 font-size: 15px;
 color:#38AE48;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.2em;
 padding-bottom: 50px
}
.fa-times{
 position: absolute;
 right: 20px;
 top:50px; 
 color:#FFF;
}
.message a{
 display: block;
 font-size:20px;
 color:#FFF;
 letter-spacing: 0.05em;
 font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
 padding-top:20px;
}

#menu_descr{
 font-size: 15px;
 color:#414141;
 margin-top:50px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.soc_net i{
 color:#414141;
 margin-right:  20px;
 margin-left:3px;
}
```

```html
<input class="open" id="top-box" type="checkbox" hidden>
<label class="btn fas fa-bars fa-2x" for="top-box"></label>
<div class="top-panel">
  <div class="message wow fadeInLeft">
    <p id="navigation">navigation<i class="fas fa-times "></i></p>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Works</a>
    <a href="#">Cliens</a>
    <a href="#">Contacts</a>
    <p id="menu_descr">Perspiciatis hic praesentium nesciunt. Et neque a dolorum voluptatem porro iusto sequi veritatis libero enim. Iusto id suscipit veritatis neque reprehenderit.</p>
    <div class="soc_net">
      <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
      <i class="fab fa-instagram  fa-2x"></i>
      <i class="fab fa-facebook  fa-2x"></i>
      <i class="fab fa-vk  fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cпасибо Вам  большое, стыдно что не додумался) <3

Comment: @АлександрПогребняк, рад помочь )